# What is the reason behind that children can cry but can't laugh?

Tags: children

I have a cousin who is almost 1 months old. As a normal child of her age, she cries a lot. But I noticed first that she doesn't laugh. So I noticed and found out that other children of her age also don't laugh. So how is it possible that childs can cry but can't laugh? What is the explanation for this?

Comment: Because life isn't funny yet. Sometimes, though, they smile in their sleep very early on, and smile socially as early as one month of age. They laugh when they can appreciate something funny - a funny face, a funny sound, a funny feeling (a 'zorbit'). Discomfort is present from the beginning, hence crying.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Why is discomfort present from beginning?

Comment: Hunger is a kind of discomfort. Cold, or being too warm, intestinal gas, uncomfortably wet diaper, being alone, having a startle reflex triggered, ad infinitum. Discomfort likely begins in utero, but believe me, every baby I ever delivered cried on delivery; I never had to slap a single one (nor did I hold them upside down. Being born is uncomfortable. Is it really a mystery?